# How to stop Win 10 from setting Jack as default as well as Microphone array?

Tags: windows-10, dell-latitude

Since the last update of Win 10, my microphone stops working in various programs.

When I go to sound in the control panel, I find both the Mic array AND Jack selected as default.

I have to select the Array and "set to default" and then the check beside Jack is removed and the Mic works.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this has disappeared as unexpectedly as it appeared. Mod: although I leave this because someone else may experience the same, feel free to delete this question.